# Is the Benny Hill Theme inherently comedic?

Tags: theory

The question is in the title. I have tried to answer it for myself, using my knowledge of music theory, and have come up with nothing. I thought it might be the V & I bass pattern, the percussion, the tempo, but I don't think that's it. I don't know Benny Hill, at all. I wouldn't recognise him if he were to walk my room, but the tune makes me laugh, and makes any video on YouTube instantly amusing.

Can music theory explain this?

Comment: A small part of it quotes Julius Fučík's *Entry of the Gladiators* (a common circus tune), which might count as associative humour rather than being inherently comedic.

Answer (score 3):

As topo morto suggests, the humor is really a byproduct of cultural association.

The Benny Hill Theme is really an arrangement of an earlier work called "[Yakety Sax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnHmskwqCCQ)" by Boots Randolph. But because it was used so often in the Benny Hill Show (often during a wacky chase scene), this music is now associated with that type of humor. Other TV shows continue that tradition today, so the music continues to be associated with that humor, and the cycle continues.

I bet you associate [Mouret's "Rondeau"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7oJ2ImdHxg) with a specific emotion as well, and it's for similar reasons: culturally, this piece is often played to accompany particular settings, so now we equate the two.

Comment: No doubt cultural association factors into this (and it's probably much older than the Benny Hill show – I guess similar music was used in circuses well before). But that doesn't really answer the question: is there any reason such music was used for comedic purposes in the first place, or was that just coincidental?

Comment: Is there something about the saxophone (e.g. in Yakety Sax) that makes it sound inherently comedic, or is that all in my head?

Comment: Cultural Association:  Thus Spake Zarathustra;   Barber Adagio For Strings;  and for us Really Old Folks, a little Beethoven for the end of Huntley-Brinkley Nightly News.